# Running java class with library from cmd

Tags: java, postgresql, libraries, javac

I have a `Baseloader.java` class which makes use of `Postgresql` database, and I have a `postgresql42.jar` file which handles the jdbc stuff.

Baseloader.java

```
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Baseloader 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, sir!");
    Connection c = null;
      try {
         Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
         c = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_base",
            "postgres", "123");
        System.out.println("Done, sir!");
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
         System.exit(0);
      }
      System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

   }
       }
```

So, when I compile and run this code through Netbeans (the postgresql.jar was included using GUI into Libraries folder) everything goes OK, the output is

```
Hello, sir!
Done, sir!
Opened database successfully
```

But when I try to run the compiled `class` file from cmd I get an error.
I placed `Baseloader.class` and `postgresql42.jar` into the same folder and cd'ed into that folder in cmd. Then I use the `java -classpath postgresql42.jar Baserunner` command which was proposed on one of the answers here, but it gava me `Could not find or load main class Baseloader` error.

If I type just `java Baseloader` it gives `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError`.

What I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

EDIT: I've changed the java version in cmd: now `java -version` gives `1.8.0_73'.`Then I checked which version Netbeans used: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"))` it also gave `1.8.0_73`.

In environmental variables the `JAVA_HOME` is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73`, while `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"))` gives `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre`. Can that difference be the case?

EDIT2: Changed `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre` with no result.
  Also `javac -version` gives the same newest `1.8.0_73` now.

Comment: Make sure your java has the same (or later) version as javac used by Netbeans to compile your class file. And I think you should use "java -cp .:postgresql42.jar Baserunner" instead.

Comment: The jdk you're using with netbeans is different than the one on your command line: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi

Comment: (@rsutormin) if this is Windows, as 'cmd' suggests, classpath delimiter is semicolon.

Comment: @blue, @rsutormin, I checked - there was Java 1.7 on cmd, so I changed the Path veriable, now `java -version` gives 1.8, but I still can't run the class from cmd..